# How do not display fan page iframe in a new window?

Tags: facebook, iframe

So, when I right click on this fan page http://www.facebook.com/Ticketmaster?v=app_204425319569897 to open it in a new window I see this http://channel.buddymedia.com/fanpage/index.php?app=f735f0c7b5a110f73ba82f0649ee0d0e

But in other pages I can see whole iframe in a new window.

Question: how do not display iframe content in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

When the content first loads inside facebook, it posts some data to the iframe. Check for that and do not load the content if it is not present.

e.g.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids']))
{
   // show content
}
else
{
  // do not show content
}
```

Note: Only do this for your landing page. The request_ids parameter is not posted to subsequent pages that load within the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something to do with the meta properties the head of the iframed content has?

That is the one thing I notice that is different between it's set up and my own (which shows the entire iframe)